# MySQL Order/limit By issue

Tags: mysql

i have a problem with a script i'm creating. I am using the PHP/SQL Statement ORDER BY. I have a topsite where i use the script below

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM topsites  WHERE categorie = '".$_GET['c']."' ORDER BY in DESC, out DESC LIMIT ".$perpage."";
```

And i need to know if there's a way i can create different pages, say first page is 1-50, second is 50-100

I have searched google for a solution to this question, but i can't seem to find anything.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. it's a MySQL thing. Read the docs on MySQL select syntax (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html). it details how to use the LIMIT clause for such things. As well, `in` is a mysql reserved word and will likely end up with syntax errors when you run that query, not to mention the gaping SQL injection hole.

Comment: [sql injection... blah, blah, Bobby Tables, escape string....](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: I assume that you mean you want _pagination_ - there are plenty of tutorials on how to implement pagination with PHP.  Also, **please** read about SQL injections.

Comment: I have tested this for SQLi and so has my partners, we have another script to prevent this. Also, i replaced the actual words with IN and OUT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT .... LIMIT CountToSkip, CountToSelect
```

The first page will be `LIMIT 0,50`, `LIMIT 50,50` on the second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The technique you are looking for is called **pagination**.  You will likely want to use SQL's `LIMIT` operator to achieve this, but there are many links on the web to point you to PHP pagination resources.

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT 0,100` , `LIMIT 100,100`

Pretty easy.